# D3 and crossfilter throw error

Tags: crossfilter

I need to make a dashboard with D3 DC and crossfilter.

The data coming from the web service is almost 1 million records.

However, crossfilter's thrown error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

What could cause crossfilter to crash in this way?

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: How would anyone be able to answer this question? Please, take the [tour], learn [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you give us an example code

Comment: Can D3 handle large sets of data?

Comment: Yeh it could but if it is a big dataset your browser could not take care but i think the problem is not on handle cuz it give you a error maximum please give an example code to see if there a problem in your code

Comment: It's company data, it's confidential, so this why I didn't post any code.

Comment: @altocumulus, I recognized this error immediately. Granted, it's not the most helpful message, but it usually indicates a common problem with this library. If anything, Mustafa's mistake was putting the javascript tag on this question - it is unlikely anyone will understand this unless they know crossfilter.

Comment: Btw, a million rows should be fine in crossfilter - maybe a little slow but workable. Much larger than that and you probably need to do some aggregation on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you have data which is not naturally ordered: i.e. you've got NaNs in your data.

https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values

The problem is that `NaN < x` is false for all numbers `x`, and `NaN > x` is also always false. So if your sorting routine does not explicitly check for invalid input, it can run forever. And if that sorting routine is recursive, it can crash.

For reasons of efficiency, crossfilter does not check its input. Maybe validation could be added without hurting efficiency?

https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/69